# Cannot set base providers error after Angular v9 upgrade using 'ng test'

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-cli

I've got all of my unit tests updated and passing after an upgrade from v8 to v9. However, now I'm getting the following error:

`Cannot set base providers because it has already been called`

Research suggested that I had `BrowserDynamicTestingModule` or `platformBrowserDynamicTesting()` called twice in my application. I searched my whole app and only found them once in my `test.ts` file:

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: {
  context(
    path: string,
    deep?: boolean,
    filter?: RegExp
  ): {
    keys(): string[];
    <T>(id: string): T;
  };
};

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

I'm not sure where else the error could come from.

Comment: Have you found any solution?